# Can you use a variable inside of a path in C?

Tags: c

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int userInput = 1;

    system("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test_"%d".txt", &userInput);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it I get 2 errors. Is it not possible to use variables like that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to format a string with a variable.

Comment: Use [sprintf](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-sprintf-method-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
You can do something like this:

```
int userInput = 1;
char path[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(path, "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test_%d.txt", userinput);
```

Comment: Better use `snprintf` than `sprintf`

Comment: @Barmar, on Windows, it's MAX_PATH.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw it worked with PATH_MAX instead of MAX_PATH

Comment: MAX_PATH is Windows specific, its defined in Windows headers.